# Keep getting error: Expecting a single value: [extent=2] in summarise

Tags: r, error-handling, dplyr

Keep getting this error when running the below script - using summarise in dplyr package

```
analysis <- df %>% group_by(Year, Week, YearWeek, Cad.Name, CamName, Abs.ID, Place.Name, Pull.Name) %>% 
  summarise(visits=sum(Visits)) %>%
  group_by(Year, Week, YearWeek, Cad.Name, CamName, Abs.ID, Place.Name) %>% 
  summarise(video=unique(Video.Name),visits=sum(Visits)) %>%
  arrange(Year,Week)
```

Video.Name was an issue and needed to add it to the groupby before summarise to get it to execute. I need to summarise by unique count of videos along my visits - any thoughts? I keep getting these errors:

```
Error: Expecting a single value: [extent=2].
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Factor `YearWeek` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na` 
2: Factor `YearWeek` contains implicit NA, consider using `forcats::fct_explicit_na`
```

Comment: It's hard to say exactly without any of your data. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with more easily

Answer (score 0):

The error should be from the `unique(Video.Name)`, which can have a `length` greater than 1 but `summarise` returns only a single row per each group.  We can wrap it in a `list`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Year, Week, YearWeek, Cad.Name, CamName, 
        Abs.ID, Place.Name, Pull.Name) %>% 
   summarise(visits=sum(Visits)) %>%
   group_by(Year, Week, YearWeek, Cad.Name, CamName, Abs.ID, Place.Name) %>% 
   summarise(video=list(unique(Video.Name)),visits=sum(Visits)) %>%
   arrange(Year, Week)
```